# Date not updating when system date changes Python

Tags: python, date

Hello!

I am working on my first program with Python. It is a window made with tkinter which displays 7 listboxes. I am using a sqlite database to store some info like date, order number and status. So the first listbox displays orders from today's date. Then the next box displays orders from tomorrow and so on. I created an .exe with pyinstaller. Everything works fine except that if i leave the program open for more than one day, when the system date changes(i'm on windows 10) it does not also change in my program. My program "thinks" the date is the same as when i executed it last time.
I get the date for each boxlike this:
day2_date=(date.today()+timedelta(days=1)) #e.g date for second box

Is there a way to refresh this or anyway to fix this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: _Is there a way to refresh this_ Yes, get the current date/time again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a matter of the flow of your program.
If `day2_date=(date.today()+timedelta(days=1))` is only invoked when reading the database at startup, it is not going to change.
This might be internal to Tk event handling, if nothing invokes the method that refresh the variable, it is not going to refresh on its own.

Comment: Thank you! I just made a function to refresh the date every couple of minutes or manually.